# Count text occurrences per line

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have to parse huge text files where certain lines are of interest and others are not. Within those of interest I have to count the occurrences of a certain keyword.

Assumed the file is called `input.txt` and it looks like this:

```
format300,format250,format300
format250,ignore,format160,format300,format300
format250,format250,format300
```

I want to exclude the lines with `ignore` and count the number of `format300`, how do I do that?

What I've got so far is this command which only counts ONCE PER LINE (which is not yet good enough):

`cat input.txt | grep -v ignore | grep 'format300' | wc -l`

Any suggestions? If possible I want to avoid using perl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need the first `cat`, that it is known as a [Useless use of cat (UUOC)](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Also, very useful is `grep -o`, that only outputs the matching patterns, one per line.

And then, count lines with `wc -l`.

```
grep -v ignore YOUR_FILE | grep -o format300 | wc -l
```

This prints `3` for your small sample.

Comment: But it should print out 5, because my sample contains 5 times `format300`

Comment: But there are 2 `format300` on the line containing `ignore`, so these 2 shouldn't count, right?

Comment: thanks, this is the perfect answer to my question, very simple and it does exactly what I asked for.

Comment: and yes, you are right of course regarding the `ignore`. All perfect!

Answer (score 9):

This one-liner should be able to do what you want:

```
grep -v ignore input.txt | sed 's/format300/format300\n/g' | grep -c "format300"
```

basically you are replacing each occurrence of your keyword with the keyword itself and a newline character, which effectively makes your input stream have the keyword only once on any given line. Then `grep -c` is counting lines with your keyword in them.

Comment: I would replace the `sed` with `tr ',' '\n'` otherwise you're going to count `format3000`s as well not just `format300`s

Comment: @1_CR, agreed, but you would also have to use `grep -xc format300` instead of `grep -c format300` to avoid false positives on "format3000".  So full solution is `grep -v ignore input.txt | tr , '\n' | grep -xc format300`

Comment: @Wildcard, indeed

Comment: Thanks guys, voted for this answer, but there was a simpler answer which I preferred over this one.

Answer (score 3):

Input file may potentially contain partial matches that would invalidate the result, for example:

```
1 format300,format250,format300
2 format250,ignore,format160,format300,format300
3 format250,format250,format300
4 format999,format300000,format999
5 format999,ignore_me_not,format300
```

You don't want to count `format300000` on line 4 or ignore line 5 because `ignore_me_not` contains the substring `ignore`.

This would do the trick:

```
grep -v "\bignore\b" FILE |grep -o "\bformat300\b"|wc -l
```

Correct output is

```
4
```

..becase line 2 is ignored, line 5 is not, and line 4 doesn't contain exactly `format300`.

If you let the `wc -l` part out, you can see what exactly is being matched:

[image]

Comment: Clever, but it goes beyond his actual stated requirements: *"I want to exclude the lines with `ignore`..."*  Your point about `format3000` et. al. is perfectly valid, though.  (As I [commented on another answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275157/count-text-occurrences-per-line#comment478183_275159).)

Comment: This is the only solution that is considering the false positives, the others so far will all fail with this input. There is still a problem, though, because the word boundaries aren't quite what are needed. A character like `-` is not a word character, so `ignore-me-not` will match `\bignore\b` but shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

A Perl way:

```
perl -lne '$k+=(s/format300//g) unless /ignore/; }{ print $k' input.txt
```

The `s/format300//g` will replace all occurrences of `format300` with nothing, and returns the number of replacements. It's a simple way of counting the occurrences. The number is then added to `$k` and the whole thing only happens if the line doesn't match `ignore`. The `}{` is perl shorthand for "do this after you've finished reading the file, so `print $k` will print the total number found.